# Controller not found within a Web forms application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, controllers

I have a project where there is a controller within a web forms application.

My controller is called Token

```
 public class TokenController : BaseTokenController
{
    public override bool IsInherited => true;


}
```

this controller inherits from BaseTokenController

```
public abstract class BaseTokenController : ApiController
{
    public abstract bool IsInherited { get; }
    public virtual bool Post([FromBody]TokenValidateArgs args)
    {
        if (!IsInherited)
            throw new Exception("Attempt to call base token controller not allowed");

        return args.Validate();
    }

    public virtual string Get()
    {
        if (!IsInherited)
            throw new Exception("Attempt to call base token controller not allowed");
        return new Token()
    }
}
```

In my global.asax I have a method called Register:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    }
```

and in global.asax Application_Start the first line of code is

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

I did have this working, however I then merged with the master branch for the project and it stopped working. I can't see anything that has changed.

this is the error:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44398/api/token'.
>   
>   
>   No type was found that matches the controller named 'token'.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue and would know how to fix this. I have read other threads and tried to fix this by putting in a RoutePrefix on the controller, moving the order of execution on the global.asax and calling the get() method directly

Answer (score 0):

So for my issue it turns out the project that has the "BaseTokenController" was running version 5.2.3 of WebApi however the web application project was running 5.2.4 which caused a conflict, resulting in a 404 error. To fix this I downgraded the app to 5.2.3